# Djangoで現在時刻をデータベースに保存したい｡

Tags: python, django

データベースに保存した時に保存した時間を登録したいのですが､次のコードを書いてみたところ､Django のサイト管理画面に項目が表示されません｡  どのように修正すれば表示されるようになりますか?  教えてください､よろしくおねがいします｡
以下にコードを記述します｡

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

# Create your models here.
class EnterInfo(models.Model):
    '''侵入者情報'''
    timeStamp = models.DateField('Intrusion time', auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.timeStamp
```

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from cms.models import EnterInfo

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(EnterInfo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auto_now` (または、`auto_now_add`)が付いているFieldは、自動的に`editable=False`になるので、admin上では非表示になります。

Django Docsより：
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield

> Note
>
> As currently implemented, setting **auto_now** or **auto_now_add** to *True*
>   will cause the field to have `editable=False` and `blank=True` set.

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます!!!